# Foreign Key Not Outputting Query Data

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

```
try {
    Statement s = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet result2 = s.executeQuery("Select Distinct * From Poem p,Recording r Where r.PoemTitle = p.PoemTitle AND r.poemTitle = 'poem1'");
    System.out.print("Result (Select with Join): ");
    while (result2.next()) {
        System.out.println(result2.getString(1)+ " " + result2.getString(2)+ result2.getString(3));
    }
} catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.print(e.getMessage());
}
```

I am trying to output the poemtitle and the date it was recorded. When this runs it outputs the poemtitle and then gives the date the poem was created instead of recorded? Is this because of the relationship?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely it's because of the `*` in the SELECT list.

Specify the columns that you want returned, in the order you want them returned.

We're just guessing at the name of the column that contains "date recorded" and which table it's in:

```
SELECT p.PoemTitle
     , r.dateRecorded
     , r.readBy
  FROM Poem p
  JOIN Recording r
    ON r.PoemTitle = p.PoemTitle
 WHERE r.poemTitle = 'poem1'
 GROUP
    BY p.PoemTitle
     , r.dateRecorded
     , r.readBy
 ORDER 
    BY p.PoemTitle
     , r.dateRecorded DESC
     , r.readBy
```

---

Notes:

Ditch the old-school comma syntax for the join operation and use the JOIN keyword instead, and relocate the join predicates from the WHERE clause to an ON clause.

Avoid using `*` in the SELECT list. Explicitly list the columns/expressions to be returned. When we read the code, and that SQL statement, we don't know how many columns are being returned, what order the columns are in, or what the datatypes are. (We'd have to go look at the table definitions.)

Explicitly listing the columns/expressions being returned only takes a little bit of work. If code was only ever written, then it would be fine, save the time writing. But code is READ ten times more than it is written. (And the SQL statement with the `*` makes the SQL statement virtually indecipherable in terms of which column is being referenced by `getString(1)`.

Listing the columns columns can also make it more efficient on the database, to prepare a resultset with a few columns vs a resultset of dozens of columns, and we also transfer a smaller resultset from the database to the client. With a subset of columns, its more likely we can use a covering index for the query.